# Не понимаю модель OSI

Tags: сеть, tcp-ip, протоколы, osi

*Простите за очень глупый вопрос.
Добрый день, я новичок в сетевых технологиях, недавно столкнулся с темой модели OSI и не понимаю её. Прочитал много вырезок из книг/статей по этой теме и вроде как осознаю что это модель по которой взаимодействуют компьютеры в сети. Но как допустим в этой модели выбирается нужный протокол, или например не понимаю термин "интерфейс", какие примитивные функции доступны допустим прикладному уровню от уровня представления. Я просто боюсь что неправильно понимаю саму модель,тк у меня постоянно возникают вопросы по этой теме и я начинаю задвать самому себе очень странные вопросы, допустим "где хранятся протоколы? ". Если возможно то не могли бы объяснить неразумному, или привестт ссылки/книги/материал который помог вам понять эту тему.

Comment: Модель OSI не работает.  Просто заучи её сдай и забудь. Протоколы есть на всех уровнях

Comment: Модель OSI - наглядный пример **декомпозиции.** Сообщение как матрёшка, собирается (от верхнего уровня к нижнему), физически доставляется к другому узлу, и разбирается в обратном порядке.
Правила взаимодействия на одном уровне, но в разных узлах, называются протоколами. Правила взаимодействия протоколов соседних уровней, на одном узле - интерфейсами.
Протоколы нигде не хранятся, они реализуются системой.