# Модель OSI понимание того, где исполняется какой уровень

Tags: сеть, osi

Не понимаю,какой уровень где(Провода, маршрутизатор, коммутатор, операционная система) исполняется.
В моём понимании происходит это так:

1. Уровень приложения - прикладной софт, под user-ом имеет интерфейс для взаимодействия по сети, больше ничего софту про сеть знать не надо - http например. Контракт есть - поехали. Это в ОС
2. Уровень представления - помечаем, что данные надо интерпретировать как json например и отдаём их из уровня приложения в формате json. Это всё ещё в ОС под user
3. Сеансовый уровень это уже ядро, у него есть интерфейс, чтобы дать сигнал уровням ниже об открытии сеанса и получить ответ что сеанс открыт и отдаёт http запрос и json с ним на транспортный уровень
4. Транспортный уровень тоже в ядре ос имеет интерфейс от уровней ниже и может получить информацию о пропускной способности , задержках и по этой информации нарезать запрос и его тело на блоки в соответствии с какими-то(какими? )протоколами, добавить свои хедеры и тп
5. Сетевой уровень режет блоки на пакеты, если блоки слишком большие(?почему транспортный не мог сделать нормальные блоки?), но тем не менее дополнительно упаковывает блоки(даже если не нарезал??) в пакеты и добавляет туда информацию о получателе(ip адрес?). То есть у этого уровня есть интерфейс к уровням ниже для того, чтобы понять в какой подсети находится получатель, выяснить его ip шлюза по умолчанию(это же роутер?) и видимо ip получателя в подсети.
6. Канальный нарезает пакеты в кадры, видимо чтобы добавить ещё больше хедеров(вопрос каких),и кидает кадры на физический уровень  и следит, чтобы они верно преобразовались в биты на физ уровне - (операционная ситсема?)
7. физ уровень - (сетевая карта??) - преобразует биты в электрические сигналы и отправляет по ip подсети, который был указан на сетевом уровне, подсеть принимает, распаковывает и внутри себя ищет по таблице маршрутизации (видимо на роутере??) нужного получателя и сетевая карта получателя получает данные от роутера в виде электрических сигналов и идёт обратный процесс.

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём я ошибся и доп вопросы помечены в скобках. К сожалению 80% материала в интернете слишком поверхностна и я ничего не понимаю

Аналогичные [вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1441165/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-osi) на руСО почему-то популярностью не пользуются и походу в принципе её мало кто по честному понимает

Comment: На мой взгляд когда описываете какой-нибудь уровень не нужно упоминать уровни выше. Иначе возникает путаница.

Comment: @Alpensin так она из моей головы идёт эта путаница, я поэтому и задал вопрос, потому что сам не всё понимаю :)

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/articles/307252/   может даже такая маленькая инфа будет полезна

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уровни считаются в обратном порядке.

7. Интерфейс между компьютером и человеком - картинка на экране. Отрисовка изображения и текста - выполняется в ос раньше, но сейчас часто приложения сами рендерят шрифты и картинки. Переводит байты в буквы.
8. Форматы файлов. Json, jpeg, HTML. В приложении через библиотеки.
9. Сеансовый - протоколы передачи того что на уровень выше. Http, sip, rtp . выполняются приложением.
10. Транспортный выполняется в ос. TCP соединения. Но транспортный может выполнятся и в приложении например при https транспортный уровень присутствует 2 раза.
11. Сетевой уровень представлен в компьютерах IP. Позволяет связать незнакомые компьютеры друг с другом и маршрутизировать передачу через роутеры. Выполняется в ос.
12. Канальный уровень выполняется в драйвере. Там видно только соседей по сети. Представлен мак адресами и протоколом arp  к примеру.
13. Физический исполняется в железе.

Любой уровень кроме крайних может быть на практике запихнут в любой другой. Уровни могут присутствовать несколько раз.

При ВПН канальный уровень запихнут в транспортный. Вот на SSTP впн канальный - в сеансовый.

А файлы можно передавать поверх канального. Минимально можно соорудить 6 сразу поверх 1.